# How to disable AdBlock Plus for local (html) files?

Tags: firefox, html, adblock

I want to disable AdBlock Plus (Firefox) for all local files. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to *AdBlock Plus > Options > Customize* and click on the *edit* Button next to *Manually edit your filters*.

Here you can add this as a new line:

```
@@file:///|$document
```

This will make an exception for all URLs beginning with the `file://` protocol, so for all your local files.

See [Writing AdBlock Plus filters](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters) for further explanation.

[image]

Comment: I discovered a nasty bug in AdBlock Plus (it cannot be turned off - https://superuser.com/questions/1283829/web-site-does-not-show-ads-googlesyndication-com-server-not-found ) so I replaced it with uBlock Origin. But thanks. +1 and accepted.