# Web site does not show ads - GoogleSyndication.com Server not found

Tags: firefox, webserver, html, javascript

I put a Google Ad in a MOST BASIC web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
</head>

<body>  
TEXT

<!-- Google ads start Sync -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google_ad_client = "ca-pub-08xxxxxxxxx";
      google_ad_slot = "4350783617";
      google_ad_width = 728;
      google_ad_height = 90;
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
  </script>
<!-- Google ads end -->

</body>
</html>
```

The page loads. There are zero errors/warnings/hints for the page content expect for Google Ads:

```
GET
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 102ms]
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20180102/r20170110/show_ads_impl.js”.
test.html:1

GET
https://adservice.google.de/adsid/integrator.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 169ms]

GET
https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 167ms]

GET
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-0896601739881432.js
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 770ms]
```

What happens? Why I can't show the ads?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in AdBlock Plus not in Firefox!!!
I disabled AdBlock Plus for that web site but it was still blocking the ads.

Once I disable the entire AdBlock Plus **addon**, the page show beautiful ads :)

---

I requested support on the forum but meanwhile I discovered uBlockOrigin which does not have this bug and seems to be lighter on resources. So, I replaced AdBlock Plus with uBlock Origin

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait for a while. In practice, the google ad won't show immediately once you update the html file.

Comment: That is true also. But they do show up in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The following patch makes it work for me locally:

```
18c18
<   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
---
>   src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
```

<sub>(Ubuntu 17.10, Firefox 57)</sub>